# "Even whiter than before," vs "even more white than before."

Tags: sentence

> Bathed in the moonlight, her skin looked even whiter than before.
>
> Bathed in the moonlight, her skin looked even more white than before.

Are both forms allowed? Which one is more common and why?

Comment: White is an adjective, it has one syllable therefore, the comparative form is *whiter*.

Comment: I would probably choose to use some form of "pale" - perhaps "her skin looked paler in the moonlight". Looking "even whiter" sounds odd to me. I've never heard anyone say that. Maybe applied to teeth - "Her teeth, already a radiant white, looked even whiter in the black light." But not skin.

Comment: Adding to what LindaBrammer said, "whiter" and "paler" have slightly different connotations, with "pale" being a little more positive due the fact that it is often associated with beauty (can't even count how many times I've seen in my studies of ancient East Asian mythology the exact phrase "considered beautiful for her pale skin and long black hair") while "white" is most frequently used in the expression "white as a sheet," which is not particularly flattering. Of course, "pale" can be used in negative contexts as well, such as "Aren't you a little pale these days?" Also consider "fair."

Comment: "Bathed in the moonlight, her milk-white skin shone like never before"

Comment: All very poetic in the comments but the question is about "white" and "whiter".  I see no problem in this context. A fair skinned person could be white because of the cold or because of shock, or just because moonlight is actually white and all colours show up as black, white, or some shade of grey in moonlight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comparative form of this word is "Whiter."

Answer (score 4):

Both forms are grammatically acceptable, with the first used far more frequently (according to [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=even+whiter%2Ceven+more+white&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceven%20whiter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceven%20more%20white%3B%2Cc0) for *even whiter,even more white*).

Note, some of the instances of *even more white* linked to at ngrams refer to quantity of white, instead of color saturation or value.  For example, in **[Crows and Jays](http://books.google.com/books?id=HTHT3DhnFAEC&pg=PA120&dq=%22even+more+white%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=g5-DUvuTK8WVkgW1kIGwCA&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22even%20more%20white%22&f=false)** the P. p. Leucoptera entry says “like last but larger and with even more white in the wing.”  This slight difference in meaning and the slight increase in length perhaps account for *even whiter* occurring more often than *even more white*.

It is famously easy to write clunky sentences containing the word *even*, and as mentioned in comments *paler* or *lighter* might be better choices than *whiter*.  Perhaps consider

> Bathed in the moonlight, her skin looked still more pale.

Answer (score 2):

**Whiter**

Yes the answer is "whiter" and it is very easy to remember if you listen to the lyrics of this famous song.

> *And so it was that later
>  As the miller told his tale
>  That her face, at first just ghostly,
>  Turned a whiter shade of pale"*
>
>  [A Whiter Shade of Pale (Procol Harum) 1967 with
> lyrics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BADDeIQWVQ)

**More white**

This collocation is of course possible but not (usually) as a comparative. It can be a noun or part of a noun phrase, e.g.

*We've run out of emulsion paint - I'll buy some more white.*

This does not mean that the new paint will be whiter than the first batch! It is an abbreviation of "some more of the white emulsion".