# the use of the word "even"

Tags: meaning

What is does the word "even" mean in this sentence?

> *It's good to be busy, **even** you missed a good lunch.*

When I heard it, it gave me the impression to mean that I am not normally busy, but now I am, so that "even" I (who I am not normally busy) missed my lunch.

Did I understand it wrong?

Comment: Either a semicolon is needed (and whether it makes sense to join these independent clauses into a single sentence is debatable) or, as Nicole says, 'even if'.

Comment: Possible duplicate (there are a LOT of questions asking about uses of "even"!) http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137475/even-whiter-than-before-vs-even-more-white-than-before

Answer (score 2):

From the context, it's most likely a typo. It makes much more sense this way:

> It's good to be busy, even **if** you missed a good lunch.

"Even if" is often used to mean "although." It's saying that although you missed a good lunch (which you normally would not want to do), it's worth it because you missed it due to being busy, and being busy is good.

Comment: It's good to be busy, though you might get a bit tired, get a bit frazzled, get a bit hungry and leave your sandwich for later – in fact, it's good to be busy, even if [that means] you miss a good lunch.